# Does mp3 work without fallback OGG in latest Firefox version?

Tags: firefox, mp3, ogg

I always used both MP3 and OGG files for playing Audio on a webpage. Mostly because Firefox didn't support the MP3 codec. I just discovered that Firefox does play MP3 files in an html5  element. Did Firefox start to support MP3 as of late? This would save a great deal of work converting MP3's into OGG's for browser compatibility.

I used this standard HTML5 audio markup

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="https://path/to/my/audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The MP3 audio format (.mp3, audio/mpeg; distinct from the above MP3 audio in an MP4 container case) is supported in  by Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS when the operating system provides an MP3 decoder" - quoting 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP3